# GDPR & Outdated Browsers

Tags: security, browsers, users, browser-support, gdpr

So as a web developer we are always asked to support the old browsers for the potential that someone may fire up a decade old computer and visit our sites.

However with GDPR now in place I wonder if that is now bad practise or even makes the site with the allowed access for old browsers to be compliant.

Everyone knows a lot of updates and security patches have been a thing of browsers and especially internet explorer. to which I know some old browsers wont even support some of the new secure technology and with that being said would it be considered no compliant for not preventing this use and keeping users secure?

What are peoples thoughts?

P.S - I know modern browsers upgrade automatically these days but the main thing I am talking about now is using browsers like IE9 or even IE6!

Comment: Security vulnerabilities in old browsers are a problem for their users not for you as owner of a website, since you can not control nor force people to use a specific tool.  And what kind of new secure technology you are thinking of that seems to be missing from old browsers but at the same time seems mandatory for GDPR compliance? I do not think there is one. GDPR is not about keeping people "secure", it deals with how personal data is handled, by whom, where, for what, etc.

Answer (score 1):

The GDPR law only affects when you manage user's data. You should check your Analytics report and see if the traffic with old browsers is relevant. If not, I'll warn those users to upgrade the browsers in order to log-in/register or use the different options in which we need to track/manage their data.

You can even prevent that traffic from using the kind of functionalities that needs user data until they upgrade.